# any API to calculate cron job instances in a date range

Tags: java, cron

Any existing API in java to calculate how many times a job (crontab) has to run between two given date/calendar instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't ask in SO to find libraries.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

**To answer your question:**
You don't need any API, third party software or a library to achieve this.

- Create a table for job executions in your database.
- Insert a record in each job execution in database.
- Make a select when needed.

Comment: not asking to recommend a tool. Just wanted to make sure i don't re-invent the wheel if one already existed. anyway thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan I know... this are the rules I didn't write them :) The point is, you must find the tool by yourself, and after, feel totally free if you want to ask any doubts using it...